# How to update a sql table column on every certain minutes interval?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-express

In a SQL Table, I have column as Start_Date, End_Date and IsActive.

On every insert, there will be a valid date time entry for Start_Date, Null for End_Date and 0 for IsActive.

After 30 mins, I need to update the End_Date with the current date time and 1 for IsActive. This is in SQL Express. I can't use job scheduler. I prefer not to use Windows Task Scheduler.

Trigger has a limitation of After Insert or Update. Is there a way to handle this ?

Comment: Why can't you use a scheduler? You have two choices here....either just set the value during insert or use a scheduled task. Sadly this is a bit bizarre. Why do you just blindly update the End_Date in 30 minutes? That makes no sense. It is just assuming it must have worked. How is this any better than just setting the value to 30 in the future when the row is created?

Comment: You could use a Service Broker queue-activated stored procedure along with a conversation timer (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187804.aspx).

Comment: The logic of using 30 mins for that row of record .. after that 30 mins, that row of record will be inactive. So i need to set the end_date timestamp

Comment: So why not just set the date when the row is inserted? It will be far easier and more accurate than updating it later.

Comment: hmm okay, set end_date time = 30mins +getdate() .. i can do that .. how about IsActive field ? This field determines the value on that row is still active of expired. I am showing the data of that row in the Web Application

Comment: Why do you need both an InactiveDate and IsActive? Wouldn't it be sufficient that is the InactiveDate is earlier than the current date that it is no longer active? I am a bit confused though, you state you want IsActive to become 1. My guess is this is a bit column and typically 1 means true but in this case IsActive would be false right? So it should become 0, or as I already said this column seems to be redundant.

Comment: Given every record is being modified to have an End_Date of Start_Date + 30 minutes by default, why not just insert the value for IsActive as 1 when the record is created. So, create a start_date, add 30 to it and set it to end_date, set IsActive to 1. Why can't you do that?

Comment: @CrazyCucumber, yes i can do that. But After 30 mins, that row of record will be come Inactive. Our front end validates the data on showing based on the IsActive Flag.  I can insert the record for start_date = get date() , End_Date = get date() + 30 mins , IsActive = 1.  After 30 mins, how do this column will get updated 0

Comment: @DanGuzman, will you please explain me about Conversation Timer concept .. In my case , after 30 mins of interval i need to update the IsActive column field to 0. This is in express edition.

Comment: @goofyui, I explained with an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example below uses a service broker activated stored procedure and conversation timer to update the table at regular intervals. Upon receipt of the DialTimer message, the activated dbo.UpdateSqlTableOnTimer proc updates the table and starts a new timer. The dbo.StartUpdateSqlTableOnTimer proc starts the initial timer and returns the conversation handle.  Specify that handle to dbo.StopUpdateSqlTableOnTimer to stop the timer loop, if needed.

Note that the database must have service broker enabled. If not already enabled, use `ALTER DATABASE` to enable service broker:

```
ALTER DATABASE YourDatabase
    SET ENABLE_BROKER;

USE YourDatabase;
GO

CREATE PROC dbo.StartUpdateSqlTableOnTimer
--begin initial conversation and timer
AS
DECLARE @ConversationHandle uniqueidentifier;
BEGIN DIALOG CONVERSATION @ConversationHandle
    FROM SERVICE UpdateSqlTableOnTimer
    TO SERVICE 'UpdateSqlTableOnTimer', 'CURRENT DATABASE'
    ON CONTRACT [DEFAULT]
    WITH ENCRYPTION = OFF;
BEGIN CONVERSATION TIMER (@ConversationHandle)  
    TIMEOUT = 1800;
SELECT @ConversationHandle AS ConversationHandle;
GO

CREATE PROC dbo.StopUpdateSqlTableOnTimer
    @ConversationHandle uniqueidentifier
--end conversation
AS
END CONVERSATION @ConversationHandle;
GO

CREATE PROC dbo.UpdateSqlTableOnTimer
AS

SET XACT_ABORT ON;
SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE
      @ConversationHandle uniqueidentifier
    , @MessageTypeName sysname
    , @EventNotificationDetails xml
    , @EventLogMessage nvarchar(MAX);

BEGIN TRY

    BEGIN TRAN;

    RECEIVE TOP(1)
            @ConversationHandle = conversation_handle
        , @MessageTypeName = message_type_name
        , @EventNotificationDetails = CAST(message_body AS xml)
    FROM dbo.QueueForUpdateSqlTableOnTimer;

    IF @@ROWCOUNT > 0
    BEGIN

        IF @MessageTypeName = N'http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQL/ServiceBroker/DialogTimer'
        BEGIN

            --update IsActive and End_Date here

            --start new timer
            BEGIN CONVERSATION TIMER (@ConversationHandle)  
                TIMEOUT = 1800; 
        END
        ELSE
        BEGIN
            IF @MessageTypeName = N'http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQL/ServiceBroker/EndDialog'
            BEGIN
                END CONVERSATION @ConversationHandle;
            END
            ELSE
            BEGIN
                END CONVERSATION @ConversationHandle WITH ERROR = 1 DESCRIPTION = 'Unexpected message type received';
            END;
        END;

    END;

    COMMIT;

END TRY
BEGIN CATCH

    IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0 ROLLBACK;
    THROW;

END CATCH;
GO

--create queue with proc activation
CREATE QUEUE dbo.QueueForUpdateSqlTableOnTimer
    WITH STATUS=ON,
    ACTIVATION (
        PROCEDURE_NAME = dbo.UpdateSqlTableOnTimer,
        MAX_QUEUE_READERS = 1,
        EXECUTE AS OWNER ) ;
GO

CREATE SERVICE UpdateSqlTableOnTimer
    ON QUEUE dbo.QueueForUpdateSqlTableOnTimer
    ([DEFAULT]);
GO

EXEC dbo.StartUpdateSqlTableOnTimer;
GO

EXEC dbo.StopUpdateSqlTableOnTimer @ConversationHandle = '<specify value from dbo.StartUpdateSqlTableOnTimer>';
GO
```

Comment: thank you so much for sharing with an example .. although our logic has been changed.. i am so thankful for sharing the service broker and conversation timer example ..